# date command on Mac bash

Tags: bash, osx, date

I have a small script in Ubuntu I want to use on a Mac. The `date` function isn't the same so it fails on syntax

Here's the original Ubuntu BASH script;

```
function pass () {
    pass="$(ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -Q -H ldap:///dc%3Dant%2Cdc%3Damazon%2Cdc%3Dcom -b DC=ant,DC=amazon,DC=com -s sub cn=$1 | grep -Ew 'pwdLastSet:' | awk '{print $2}')"
    pass_epoch="$(((pass / 10000000) - 11644473600))"
    pass_epoch_exp="$((pass_epoch + 86400*90))"
    today="$(date +%s)"
    countdown_epoch="$(expr $pass_epoch_exp - $today)"
    countdown="$((countdown_epoch / 86400))"
    pwdSet_date="$(date -d @$pass_epoch)"
    expires_date=$(date -d "@$((pass_epoch + 86400*90))")
    echo "pwdLastSet: "$pwdSet_date
    echo "pwdExpires: "$expires_date
    echo "  daysLeft: "$countdown
}

usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
pwdLastSet: 
pwdExpires: 
  daysLeft: 23
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MacOs is not the same family of UNIX as Linux, so options for commands can be different.

**SOLUTION 1** :  `man date` is your friend.

On MacOS, you need to use a combination of `-j` and `-f` .

```
E444:~ emas$ date -j -f %Y%m%d-%H%M%S 20180101-234852  +%Y/%m/%d\ %H:%M:%S
2018/01/01 23:48:52
E44:~ emas$ date -j -f %Y%m%d-%H%M%S 20180101-234852  +%s
1514868532
E444:~ emas$ date -j -f %s 1514868532
Mon Jan  1 23:48:52 EST 2018
```

**SOLUTION 2** : use brew ( https://brew.sh/ ) to install some GNU/Linux tools.

`brew install coreutils`  will install many basics tools and prefix them with `g`, so `date` becomes `gdate` and is located in your `/usr/local/` folder.