# trying to add X hours to an arbitrary date in bash

Tags: bash, date

Given a date string like this:
2022-03-28T23:40:49.721Z

I am trying to add X hours.

the function would look similar to

```
addHours()
{
   dateString=$1 
   hours=$2

   return date -d 'dateString + $hours hours' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'
}
```

My issue is the 'T' is causing issues and I keep running into invalid date structure

Comment: that's not because of the `T`, change `return date -d 'dateString + $hours hours' +....` to `return date -d "$dateString + $hours hours" +....`, that should probably work.

Comment: date -d '2022-03-28T23:40:49.721Z +6 hours' +'%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ' seems to work in ubuntu, but not on a MAC.. how to do this so it works on my MAC?

Comment: maybe this is related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550305/72456

Answer (score 1):

In Unix this worked:

```
date -d '2022-03-28T23:40:49.721Z +6 hours' +'%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ'
```

But on a Mac I needed to convert to Timestamp, do the math, then convert back:

```
dateFormatter() 
{
    date -jf "%s" $1 +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
}

dateAddTime()
{
    ds=$1
    echo $ds
    # remove nano seconds
    ds=`echo "${ds/\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]/}"`
    
    #convert to timestamp
    ts=`date -jf %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ $ds  +%s`

    #time in hours
    seconds=$2*60*60
    
    
    dateFormatter $(($ts + $seconds))
}

#add 6 hours
dateAddTime 2022-03-28T23:40:49.721Z 6
```

NOTE: MacOS does not like the nanoseconds, so that had to be removed.